# understanding the split method output in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and studying it as part of a data structures and algorithms module.

We are looking at methods available for Strings and in particular the `.split()`

```
myString = 'abracadabra'

print (myString.split('a'))
```

When the code is run the output looks like ['', 'br', 'c', 'd', 'br', '']

Why is python grouping the "br" together rather than outputting something like  [",'b','r','c','d','b','r','']

Comment: Python isn't grouping anything. It only cuts the string where there was an `'a'`. There's no `'a'` in 'br', so Python doesn't split it at this position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layman terms:

`.split('a')` will use 'a' as a delimiter.

Think of it this way:

1. It replaces each 'a' with a space.
2. It then returns an array containing all of the words.

For example, if `myString` is `'abracadabra`, it will do this:

`'abracadabra'` --> `' br c dbr '` --> `['br', 'c', 'd, 'br']`

If you do `.split()` on `myString` and run a `list()` on it, it will return an array containing each character as individual elements. In this case, `myString.split()` --> `['a', 'b', 'r', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'r', 'a']`

Comment: *it will return each character as a single element* - no it won't... it'll return a list of items split by any whitespace... In this case, a list with one item...

Comment: @JonClements You're right, my phrasing is wrong. I meant to say each character is a single element. Editing my answer...

Comment: That's not the output of `myString.split()` though... (which now seems to be called `.spit()` :0 (`list(myString)` will give you that... not `str.split()`)

Comment: @JonClements Changed `.spit()` and my phrasing... Ty

Comment: The last sentence is still wrong. The last list has nothing to do with `split`. It's just the result of `list('abracadabra')`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
 str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)

     Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter 
     string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list
     will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1,
     then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

      If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together 
      and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, 
      '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']). The sep argument may 
      consist of multiple characters (for example, '1<>2<>3'.split('<>') 
      returns ['1', '2', '3']). Splitting an empty string with a 
      specified separator returns [''].
```